# How to set the emission intensity of a material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set the emission intensity of a material so that I can set it to a given value say 0.5, -0.7, etc.

Instead of multiplying the colour as given in the code below, how do I set it to a value given by me?

[image: Emission Intensity]

```
 public GameObject Yellow;
 void Start()
 {
  Yellow.GetComponent<Renderer>();
  Material mat = Yellow.material;

  Color colour = mat.GetColor("_EmissionColor");
  colour *= 4f; //  4X brighter
  mat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", colour);
 }
```

Comment: mat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(r, g, b, a)); Where r, g, b, a are values of your own choice...?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question, You can set the value in the inspector by making it a public variable in the script on the GameObject.

```
public float Intensity = .1f; //default value
void SetColor()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetColor("_EmissionColor") * Intensity;
}
```

Then set the variable in the inspect.

This can also be achieved with shaders. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am getting this error:
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.